# How to call method with callback from jni

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

How to call `read` method in `Usb.java` from `JNI`?

```
    static jclass _clsUsbController;
    static jfieldID _fldUsbController;
    static jobject _objUsbController;
    static jmethodID _midRead;

    // read mid
    static const char *MID_READ = "read";

    // read sig
    static const char *SIG_READ = "(Lid/ctech/dispenser_pos/dev/comm/devices/usb/IUsb$IUsbWriteCallback;)V";

    // read method id
    _midRead = e->GetMethodID(_clsUsbController, MID_READ, SIG_READ);
    if (_midRead == null || isExceptionOccurred()) {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    // call read method
    arrRes = (jbyteArray) e->CallObjectMethod(_objUsbController, _midRead);
```

\app\src\main\java\id\ctech\dispenser_pos\dev\comm\devices\usb\IUsb.java

```
package id.ctech.dispenser_pos.dev.comm.devices.usb;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public interface IUsb {

    void read(@NonNull IUsbReadCallback callback);

    interface IUsbReadCallback {

        void onSuccess(byte[] result);

        void onError(@NonNull Throwable result);
    }
    
}
```

\app\src\main\java\id\ctech\dispenser_pos\dev\comm\devices\usb\Usb.java

```
package id.ctech.dispenser_pos.dev.comm.devices.usb;

public class Usb implements IUsb {

    @Override
    public synchronized void read(@NonNull IUsbWriteCallback callback) {

         // ...

    }

 }
```